# Leaflet polygons cut off on map viewport while dragging

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using mapbox library for one of my fleet_management application and i have created circle & polygon leaflet on map.

Current behavior: When dragging polygons or circles are on map only partly in the viewport, the part of the polygons or circles that were out of the viewport are cut off,

So i used panTO for center map at requested coordinate,but sometimes panTo() does not center map at requested coordinate(leaflets like circle and polygon).

```
this.map.panTo(this.shape._latlng);
```

Desired behavior: When dragging the polygon or circle it should come center of the map and it should load properly(Don't cut off).

The problem is present in https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/2814, see this github link.

Comment: Hello what is wrong with this question i clearly mentioned my issue and given a link also,why u gave minus,if u don't know the answer means leave it,simply doing this kind of things is not good

Comment: or else whats wrong is there in my question plz put a comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start observing 'isDrag'(Dragged or not) property. When latlng changes polygon will be centered.

```
geofenceDrag: function() {
    if (!_.isNull(this.shape))
        this.map.panTo(this.shape._latlng);
    }
}.observes('isDrag')
```